# How to output json with loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some JSON file:

```
"productsAtributesMaping":[
    {
        "model":"first",
        "params":["0", "1", "2"]
    },
    {
        "model":"second",
        "params":["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"]
    }
]
```

How to output a params of each object with loop?

Comment: Server side or client side?

Comment: First of all, it is an invalid json..

Comment: it's client side. JSON is vaild, it's a part of them

Comment: @Manishankar It's only missing parent braces, so I would assume this is just a property of a larger object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each()` like this:

```
$.each(data.productsAtributesMaping, function(i, val) {
    $.each(val.params, function(x, param) {
        console.log(param);
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NmMVy/)

Comment: This place is unbelievable. Give an answer with a demonstration of it working and still get an unexplained downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) and `for..in` loop:

```
// fill in `jsonData` variable
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);
for(var i in obj) {
    var item = obj[i];
    console.log(item.model);
    console.log(item.params);
}
```

Comment: The data is already in JSON format, so `parseJSON` is not required. Also, params will output as a joined string, not iterated over as the OP required.